# Android spell checking with HTML

Tags: android, html, android-spellcheck

Android's native browser does not support the spellcheck="true" HTML varible, is there a replacement I could use from the standard webView, e.g. crosswalk that would support spellcheck="ture"?

Or is should I use the spell checker frame work, and would the spell checker frame work underline incorrect spellings with a red line?